# Why is a merged JavaScript temp file malformed?

Tags: javascript, templates, typo3-6.2.x

TYPO3 prepares temporary JavaScript files for its webside. JavaScript parts from different other places are merged, either from static template or plugins or else.

So I have this file called `merged-3bd3eaa073b37b8d1d1d0c04d7722ce8-38ba5c107f8fdbb8b9e1f350a437a721.js`, which contains some mangled chars. See below.

I can fix this by editing the temp file but in fact the next time somebody clears the cache, it is created from start with the mangled chars.

Does somebody know about this phenomenon, or can somebody show me a simple way to track this down? What should I make of this part `...com.apple.quarantine...`?

I use TYPO3 6.2.

Thanks a lot.

---

```
...
...
/**
 * Callback method for the module menu
 *
 * @return {TYPO3.Components.PageTree.App}
 */
TYPO3.ModuleMenu.App.registerNavigationComponent('typo3-pagetree', function() {
TYPO3.Backend.NavigationContainer.PageTree = new TYPO3.Components.PageTree.App();

    // compatibility code
top.nav = TYPO3.Backend.NavigationContainer.PageTree;
top.nav_frame = TYPO3.Backend.NavigationContainer.PageTree;
top.content.nav_frame = TYPO3.Backend.NavigationContainer.PageTree;

return TYPO3.Backend.NavigationContainer.PageTree;
});

// XTYPE Registration
Ext.reg('TYPO3.Components.PageTree.App', TYPO3.Components.PageTree.App);

����Mac OS X        ����   ���2���¬������Þ��������������������������������������ATTR�������Þ���˜���F������������������˜���F��com.apple.quarantine�q/0001;55e68bf3;Google\x20Chrome;ABDF451E-D20F-4849-9A6E-6870D1CAF80D�
����Mac OS X        ����   ���2���¬������Þ��������������������������������������ATTR�������Þ���˜���F������������������˜���F��com.apple.quarantine�q/0001;55e68bf3;Google\x20Chrome;ABDF451E-D20F-4849-9A6E-6870D1CAF80D�
����Mac OS X        ����   ���2���¬������Þ��������������������������������������ATTR�������Þ���˜���F������������������˜���F��com.apple.quarantine�q/0001;55e68bf3;Google\x20Chrome;ABDF451E-D20F-4849-9A6E-6870D1CAF80D�
����Mac OS X        ����   ���2���¬������Þ��������������������������������������ATTR�������Þ���˜���F������������������˜���F��com.apple.quarantine�q/0001;55e68bf3;Google\x20Chrome;ABDF451E-D20F-4849-9A6E-6870D1CAF80D�
����Mac OS X        ����   ���2���¬������Þ��������������������������������������ATTR�������Þ���˜���F������������������˜���F��com.apple.quarantine�q/0001;55e68bf3;Google\x20Chrome;ABDF451E-D20F-4849-9A6E-6870D1CAF80D�
����Mac OS X        ����   ���2���¬������Þ��������������������������������������ATTR�������Þ���˜���F������������������˜���F��com.apple.quarantine�q/0001;55e68bf3;Google\x20Chrome;ABDF451E-D20F-4849-9A6E-6870D1CAF80D�
����Mac OS X        ����   ���2���¬������Þ��������������������������������������ATTR�������Þ���˜���F������������������˜���F��com.apple.quarantine�q/0001;55e68bf3;Google\x20Chrome;ABDF451E-D20F-4849-9A6E-6870D1CAF80D�
����Mac OS X        ����   ���2���¬������Þ��������������������������������������ATTR�������Þ���˜���F������������������˜���F��com.apple.quarantine�q/0001;55e68bf3;Google\x20Chrome;ABDF451E-D20F-4849-9A6E-6870D1CAF80D�
����Mac OS X        ����   ���2���¬������Þ��������������������������������������ATTR�������Þ���˜���F������������������˜���F��com.apple.quarantine�q/0001;55e68bf3;Google\x20Chrome;ABDF451E-D20F-4849-9A6E-6870D1CAF80D�
����Mac OS X        ����   ���2���¬������Þ��������������������������������������ATTR�������Þ���˜���F������������������˜���F��com.apple.quarantine�q/0001;55e68bf3;Google\x20Chrome;ABDF451E-D20F-4849-9A6E-6870D1CAF80D�
/*
 * This code has been copied from Project_CMS
 * Copyright (c) 2005 by Phillip Berndt (www.pberndt.com)
 *
 * Extended Textarea for IE and Firefox browsers
 * Features:
 *  - Possibility to place tabs in <textarea> elements using a simply <TAB> key
 *  - Auto-indenting of new lines
 *
 * License: GNU General Public License
 */
 ...
 ...
```

Comment: Do any of the directories that contain the original JS have hidden files (starting with `.`) in them?

Answer (score 0):

Please try following on your mac-osx terminal:

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /path/to/folder/merged-3bd3eaa073b37b8d1d1d0c04d7722ce8-38ba5c107f8fdbb8b9e1f350a437a721.js
```